# Add calling NUnit test to NLog output

Tags: nunit, nlog

I am running tests through NUnit and want to have NLog messages quickly tell me the calling test on each log message. Something like

```
<target xsi:type="File" 
          layout="${longdate} ${someMagic} ${message}"
          />
```

Is there an easy way to do that without diving too deep into NLog code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working solution: a set of extension methods that wrap NLog `ILogger.Error(..)` method and the likes, looking up the stack for NUnit `[Test]` or `[TestCase]` Attributes

```
    public static void XError(this ILogger log, String message)
    {
        if (log.IsErrorEnabled == false)
            return;

        var prefix = GetCallerTestDescription();
        log.Error("[{0}] {1}", prefix, message);
    }

    private static string GetCallerTestDescription()
    {
        var stack = new StackTrace(false).GetFrames();

        if (stack != null)
        {
            foreach (var frame in stack)
            {
                var method = frame.GetMethod();
                var testAttributes = method.GetCustomAttributes<TestAttribute>();

                if (testAttributes != null && testAttributes.Any())
                {
                    return method.Name;
                }

                var tcAttributes = method.GetCustomAttributes<TestCaseAttribute>();
                if (tcAttributes != null && tcAttributes.Any())
                {
                    return method.Name;
                }

            }
        }
```